# how to use push notification in iphone SDK3.0?

Tags: iphone

i am new in the iphone application development. first tell me what is push notification? Why we use push notification? and last how we can use push notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push Notification is where a remote server can send messages and sounds to iPhones and iPod touches who may or may not be running your application at the time the message is sent. That is, it's a way of getting around the fact that the iPhone does not allow third part applications to run in the back ground.

Apple have documented this pretty well. See the [Push Notification Service Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) for more details.